# Unable to check in some files using svn

Tags: svn

I'm new to svn. I'm using `Ubuntu 11.10. svn version 1.6.12` I tried checking in, only few files got checkedin. Rest of the files are displayed when I do `svn status` and when I try to checkin this files nothing happens, no error or message is displayed. I did `svn cleanup`, still no change.
  Can anyone guide me on how to checkin all this files into the repository.

Comment: Do the files listed in `svn status` have question marks `?` next to them?

Comment: @Mike Yes they have ? marks. What does it indicate? What has to be done

Comment: svn add <filename> then svn checkin (for new files).

Comment: @JamesWoolfenden There are around 100 files. Should I do svn add for each file and checkin for each file

Answer (score 1):

Finally did the following steps to check in succesfully-

```
svn add *
```

and then `svn ci -m "update"`

Comment: Actually, if the files are marked with an `?` in `svn st`, you do not need the `--force` option. A simple `svn add filename` should suffice.